# issue with adding strings to the page dynamically using a for loop

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add three sentences to the page dynamically using a for loop.  The issue is all the sentences in the `Sentences` array lie on each other in the output instead of each sentence in the new line.

Here is the code so far:

```js
let Sentences = [

'i was sent to earth to protect you.',

'they have been working around here.',

'just another example sentence.',

];


generateSentences();

function generateSentences() {

    for(let i = 0; i < Sentences.length; i++){

      let addSentence = document.getElementById(`Sentence${i}`);

      let sentence = '';
      sentence = `<span>${Sentences[i]}</span>`;
      addSentence.innerHTML = `${sentence}`;

    } // end of for loop
 
};
```

```css
.container {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 8.7vw;
    top: 25vh;
    height: 55vh;
    width: 82vw;   
    outline: 0.1vw dashed orange;
}

.main-class {
    position: absolute;
    white-space: pre-wrap; 
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;  
    font-weight:400;
    color: #595959;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.Sentence-class1 {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 40;
}


.Sentence-class2 {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 20;
}

.Sentence-class3 {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="containerAnswering"> 

<div id="Sentence0" class="main-class Sentence-class1"></div>
<div id="Sentence1" class="main-class Sentence-class2"></div>
<div id="Sentence2" class="main-class Sentence-class3"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: `bottom: 40` -> `bottom: 40px`? You're missing a unit there.

Comment: Don't use `position: absolute`

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with the javascript, at all, and i don't understand, how even a little testing wouldn't make that obvious.

Comment: @ASDFGerte Don't let new comers down. Let them learn and thrive. People like us should lift them up and teach them. We all once a fresher

Comment: Here's a dynamic solution: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/Lucp8g97/

Comment: @NithinChandran I can always be wrong, but i will voice concerns, when i feel like people spent very little time trying to solve the problem, before asking on SO. If they indeed made almost no effort themselves, it's a problem. If they did effort, but don't show it in their questions, it's a problem. Lets say they did actually try (the only interesting case), and didn't manage to notice, that this is unrelated to JS. In that case, a fundamental misunderstanding about some topics is to be assumed. Mentioning that (even better, solving the misunderstanding), would be an important lesson.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to center all the three sentence divs, as that will make them overlap on each other.  Instead, you use something like below.

Also, it will help to use `flex-direction: column` if you want each sentence to appear one below the other.

Also, if you need spacing between sentences, you can define a class such as `sentence` and use CSS `margin` to add spacing.

```js
let Sentences = [

'i was sent to earth to protect you.',

'they have been working around here.',

'just another example sentence.',

];


generateSentences();

function generateSentences() {

    for(let i = 0; i < Sentences.length; i++){

      let addSentence = document.getElementById(`Sentence${i}`);

      let sentence = '';
      sentence = `<span>${Sentences[i]}</span>`;
      addSentence.innerHTML = `${sentence}`;

    } // end of for loop
 
};
```

```css
.container {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 8.7vw;
    top: 25vh;
    height: 55vh;
    width: 82vw;   
    outline: 0.1vw dashed orange;
}

.main-class {
    position: absolute;
    white-space: pre-wrap; 
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;  
    font-weight:400;
    color: #595959;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.sentence {
  margin: 8px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="containerAnswering"> 

<div class="main-class">
  <div id="Sentence0" class="sentence"></div>
  <div id="Sentence1" class="sentence"></div>
  <div id="Sentence2" class="sentence"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer... Is there any solution to increase the space between sentences? I used classes to take control of the space between sentences!

Comment: @foxer you can always use margin, or padding to control how far apart elements are.

Comment: @foxer Yes - you could use margin.  I have updated the example by adding `sentence` class

Answer (score 0):

The main issue you're having is that you haven't provided units for your css "bottom" properties, such as px, rem, etc. Anything other than 0 will need an explicit unit specified, depending on the browser. For instance:

```
.Sentence-class1 {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 40px;
}
```

I also just want to point out that your container element's class is "containerAnswering" in the HTML but just "container" in the CSS. Unless maybe you were referencing another element not shown here... but just thought I should point that out in case.